# Targeting an element and other elements under it with the value of that element in a xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an xml document like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Awmds>
    <title>It is a xml</title>
    <segment>
      <reference>HASL11</reference>
      <code>MSB</code>
    </segment>
    <segment>
      <reference>HASL12</reference>
      <code>MSB</code>
    </segment>
</Awmds>
```

I can parse and extract the value of the **title** element, using jquery, like this -

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    $title = $xml.find("title");
```

Here, xml data is passed by the variable **xml**.
 What i want to do is to target the corresponding **segment** or **code** element, with the value **HASL11**, which is a value of the element **reference**. How can i achieve this ?

Here is a live [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ni8mr/6kd6h6v4/10/) demonstrating my code.

Comment: Use `:contains()` selector like `$xml.find("reference:contains(HASL11)").parent()`

Comment: Will it access the whole "segment" ? And if it is accessed, how can i target "code" after that ?

Comment: `:contain(HASL11)` select element has `HASL11` text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you want specifically but something like the following should help

```
var $seg = $xml.find('segment').has('reference:contains(HASL11)');
var code = $seg.find('code').text()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/sbw3RbuGJ6XiUVIE1mBa?p=preview)**</kbd>